# How I can filter my DataTable by Column Value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, filter, datatable, adapter

I have a question about `DataTable`. I retrieve a `DataTable` from the database, and one of these columns contains either a 1 or a 0. Now I want to retrieve only the rows with a 1 value of 1 in that column.

The name of the column is `ACTIVATE`.

Here is my `DataTable`:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable(TABLE);

//How can I filter here so ACTIVATE == 1?

adapter.Fill(table);

connection.Open();

selectcommand.ExecuteReader();

return table;
```

Comment: Aren't you using a query to fill the datatable?? Use a where condition in that query

Comment: Do the logic in the query, pass null to return all with a parameter WHERE (@filter is NULL OR ACTIVATE = @filter)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Via SQL (preferred)

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WHERE ACTIVATE = 1
```

Via `Linq-To-Datatable` (in memory):

```
DataTable tblFiltered = table.AsEnumerable()
                             .Where(r => r.Field<int>("ACTIVATE") == 1)
                             .CopyToDataTable();
```

If you're still on .NET 2, you can use [`DataTable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx):

```
DataRow[] filteredRows = table.Select("ACTIVATE = 1");
```

Apart from that, you don't need `selectcommand.ExecuteReader()` to fill the table.

```
DataTable table = new Datatable();
using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WHERE ACTIVATE = 1", con))
using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    da.Fill( table );
}
```

Comment: add a Datatable.Select() filter, and this answer would be complete. :)

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore: Why? Linq is much more powerful and the strong typed `Field` methods which also supports nullables are the better choice(if available). Edit: However, you're right. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: +1 offcourse it it, i just said that so to cover all options in one answer.

Comment: Datatable.Select is slow like hell, especially with larger number of records

Comment: @AntonioBakula did'nt knew that...thanxx, i learned something new today..!! This answer must be accepted then.

Comment: `CopyToDataTable()` saved me.

Answer (score 5):

```
DataTable results = table.Select("ACTIVATE = 1").CopyToDataTable();
```

That should achieve what you want, basically you can query data tables much like SQL.

Answer (score 4):

You simply use [DataTable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) like this:

```
 foundRows = table.Select("ACTIVATE = '1'");
```

It returns an array of DataRow objects.

Answer (score 3):

```
return table;
DataTable results = table.Select("ACTIVATE = 1").CopyToDataTable();
```