# Choose specific column from datatable and compare the value to string

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically I want to know how to select a specific column by calling its name and compare its row value to a string/int.

This is my datatable https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgYVd.png

[image]

Something like this: [iterate through particular column in a datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434750/iterate-through-particular-column-in-a-datatable)

```
        adp.Fill(ds); //Fill Dataset
        dt = ds.Tables[0]; //Then assign table to dt


        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {


        }
```

Comment: `if (Convert.ToInt32(row["column"]) == 1)`

Comment: Plenty of answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760072/select-certain-columns-of-a-data-table

Comment: if it's really an `int` i'd use `bool isMyPort = row.Field<int>("Master_Port") == yourPort`. One advantage, it supports nullables, so if this column can contain `DbNull`s you can write: `int? port = row.Field<int?>("Master_Port")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the column name to get the value as like below

```
int Value;
bool IsInteger;

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{  
IsInteger = int.TryParse(row["columnname"].ToString(), out Value);

if(!IsInteger)
{
}
}
```

Comment: Is there a compact way to do that with 3 different colums?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use DataRow.Field extension method from System.Data.DataSetExtensions package, its a generic method that does type conversion for you, also takes in column as DataColumn, column index or string column name.

```
foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
{
    dataRow.Field<string>("mycolumn");
}
```

Comment: How do i add an if/else to that?

Comment: I have a feeling this is what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/13701216/1343192